# Meaning of "ball that lands in a bin by itself"

Tags: probability-theory

I am struggling to understand the meaning of the question, i.e. I do not understand what the question asks.

The exercise is from *Probability and Computing* book, Exercise 5.11, pg 121. This is the problem statement.

> The following problem models a simple distributed system wherein
>   agents contend for resources but "back off" in the face of contention. Balls represent agents, and bins represent resources.
>
> The system evolves over rounds. Every round. balls are thrown independently and uniformly at random into 11 bins. **Any ball that lands in a bin by itself** is served and removed from consideration. The remaining balls are thrown again in the next round. We begin with n balls in the first round, and we finish when every ball is served.
>
> a) If there are b balls at the start of a round. what is the expected number of balls at the start of the next round?

I am not asking for a solution or how to solve it. What I don't understand is the part of the sentence "*Any ball that lands in a bin by itself*". What does it mean "landing in a bin by itself"?

I understand that we throw $b$ balls in $n$ bins, and balls land in bins. But I can't imagine how a ball can land in a bin NOT "by itself". After all we blindly throw balls in bins and balls themselves land in bins, i.e. we do not put them deliberately in bins.

Comment: *served* is also an unfortunate word here.  Not only does it have the  meaning intended here similar to queuing theory, but with balls it has a different meaning in tennis and other similar sports

Comment: I would take it to mean that it means the ball lands in a bin and is the only ball in the bin.  But it is not clear.  Also not clear is whether it is assumed all balls land in bins and we never miss and have a ball land on  the floor.  By this language I would *NOT* have assumed any such thing, but as we have no idea how good we are at throwing balls, how big the bins are to the floor, etc.  the question would be utterly unanswerable if we *didn't* assume that.  Rest assured: It is not you; the english in the book is *terrible*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Source: Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by%20itself)

The phrase "by itself" has two main meanings:

- without being directly controlled by a person; automatically
- with nothing nearby; alone

The second sense is meant here; the ball is alone. It is the only ball in its bin.